# Oracle DB Update statement, same value different targeted rows

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-update, oracle-sqldeveloper

In my procedure I want to insert in table order and update table salesman

```
create or replace PROCEDURE place_order(
    PURCH_AMT   in varchar,
    CUSTOMER_ID in varchar,
    SALESMAN_ID in varchar
) AS
order_id varchar(50);
ORD_DATE varchar(50);

--INICIO
begin
    --VARS
        order_id := sys_guid();
        ORD_DATE := SYSDATE;
    --INSERT da order
        insert into ORDERS values (order_id, PURCH_AMT, ORD_DATE, CUSTOMER_ID, SALESMAN_ID);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('out put with variable salesman_id');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(SALESMAN_ID);
    --UPDATE sales do salesman
        update salesman
        set n_sales = n_sales + 1
        where salesman.SALESMAN_ID = SALESMAN_ID;
    --COMMIT
        COMMIT;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            ROLLBACK;
            RAISE;     
        
end place_order;
```

But when I run it it updates all the salesman[image: TABLE AND OUTPUT]

When I change the update on the procedure and hard code the salesman ID it works

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('output with harcoded 5001');
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(5001);
    --UPDATE sales do salesman
        update salesman
        set n_sales = n_sales + 1
        where salesman.SALESMAN_ID = '5001';
```

[image: UPDATE working]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE place_order(
    PURCH_AMT   in varchar,
    CUSTOMER_ID in varchar,
    SALESMAN_ID in varchar          --> this
) AS
<snip>
    --UPDATE sales do salesman
        update salesman
        set n_sales = n_sales + 1
        where salesman.SALESMAN_ID = SALESMAN_ID;
                       -----------   -----------
                         this
```

**Never** name parameters the same as column names. As you did it, `where` clause was evaluated to something similar to `where 1 = 1` which means *update ALL rows in that table*.

Rename parameters; usually, we *prefix* them, e.g.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE place_order(
    PAR_PURCH_AMT   in varchar2,
    PAR_CUSTOMER_ID in varchar2,
    PAR_SALESMAN_ID in varchar2
) AS
<snip>
    --UPDATE sales do salesman
        update salesman
        set n_sales = n_sales + 1
        where salesman.SALESMAN_ID = PAR_SALESMAN_ID;
```

---

(Also, Oracle recommends us to use `varchar2` instead of `varchar`)